# Can you identify what sets this partial build and bag of LEGO elements come from?

Tags: set-identification

We got this big box of Lego bricks, and we don't have the manuals, please help!

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Bricks.SE! The bag numbered 2 is from set [9494 Anakin’s Jedi Interceptor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9494-1#T=P).

[image]

This is all based on the included [Windscreen 10 x 6 x 3 Bubble Canopy Double Tapered with Light Bluish Gray Jedi Starfighter Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50986pb003&in=S) which only appears in this set (there is an older version of this piece but it is too old to have been included in the bag pictured, which LEGO didn’t start using until 2011).

[image]

The second picture contains a child’s own creation out of various pieces, including a [Windscreen 6 x 6 x 3 Canopy Half Sphere with Dual 2 Fingers and SW Tie-Fighter Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50747pb06&name=Windscreen%206%20x%206%20x%203%20Canopy%20Half%20Sphere%20with%20Dual%202%20Fingers%20and%20SW%20Tie-Fighter%20Pattern&category=%5BWindscreen,%20Decorated%5D#T=P&C=13).

[image]

This piece also comes only in one set, namely set [9492 TIE Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9492-1#T=P). Both sets are from 2012.

[image]